# Creating a list of forms with a prefix. Help to simplify

Tags: python, django

Here is a working code, but I don't like it's ugliness. Please, suggest more pythonic and elegent way of creating this lists. More Python than Django question. Here is the code:

```
order = Order.objects.get(pk=pk)
items = Item.objects.all()
if request.method == 'POST':
    #OrderItem model has a foreign field "order" to Order model
    instance = OrderItem.objects.filter(order=order)
    items_forms = [OrderItemForm(request.POST, prefix=str(x), instance=instance[x]) for x in
                       range(0, Item.objects.count())]
    #saving forms here
    return redirect('/step2/')
items_forms = [ItemForm(prefix=str(x)) for x in range(0, Item.objects.count())]
return {'forms': items_forms , 'items': items}
```

Comment: Which part of that is ugly?

Comment: Actually, it's a list comprehensions wich are to long and are not readably. Maybe there is a way to refactor it a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a list of identical forms, you should use a [formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/formsets/) (or a [model formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets)).